# What are getServletContextLocal() and getServletContextProvider()

Tags: java, portlet, spring-portlet-mvc, portletbridge

In the tutorials I read I came across getServletContext() but what are these 2 for ?
This is how the line looks:

```
ServletContext sc = getServletContextProvider().getServletContextLocal();
```

How is this different from:

```
 ServletContext sc = getServletContext();
```

Comment: i dont even know what portlets are, I am just looking over a server code in java to figure it out how it works, it uses servlets(kind of a beginner in this)

Comment: it looks like related to portlets.

Comment: i think so, do you know what they do ?

Answer (score 0):

Your answer is specific to the class likely implementing a `ServletContextProvider` interface.  In order to answer this properly, you need to provide the package where `ServletContextProvider` is declared, or even more helpful, the class or interface which contains the `getServletContextProvider()` and `getServletContext()` methods (declared or abstract).

Even easier for us, provide a link to the tutorial you reference, or some additional context (no pun intended).  The only references to a `getServletContextLocal` method on the internet (after a Google search) are either this question, or copies of this question.

Assuming `getServletContextProvider()` returns a `ServletContextProvider` class or interface, there are several interfaces and classes available with that name; I'll go through each one I found:

1. Interface [org.apache.portals.bridges.common.ServletContextProvider](http://portals.apache.org/bridges/index.html) does not have a `getServletContextLocal()` method.
2. Interface [com.liferay.portal.kernal.servlet.ServletContextProvider](http://docs.liferay.com/portal/6.0/javadocs/com/liferay/portal/kernel/servlet/ServletContextProvider.html) doesn't have a `getServletContextLocal()` method; Implementer of said interface, `LiferayServletContextProvider` doesn't have the `getServletContextLocal()` method, and extends Object.
3. Class [ca.grimoire.maven.ServletContextProvider](http://www.jarvana.com/jarvana/view/ca/grimoire/maven/maven-utils/1.1/maven-utils-1.1-javadoc.jar!/ca/grimoire/maven/ServletContextProvider.html) doesn't have a `getServletContextLocal()` method, nor does the `ResourceProvider` interface it implements, and it extends Object.
4. Interface [org.atmosphere.di.ServletContextProvider](http://atmosphere.java.net/nonav/apidocs/org/atmosphere/di/ServletContextProvider.html) does not have a `getServletContextLocal()` method, nor do the 4 implementing classes listed on that link.
5. Class [com.atlassian.jira.web.ServletContextProvider](http://docs.atlassian.com/jira/latest/com/atlassian/jira/web/ServletContextProvider.html) not have a `getServletContextLocal()` method, and extends Object.
6. Abstract Class [org.kaleidofoundry.core.web.ServletContextProvider](http://code.google.com/p/kaleido-foundry/source/browse/trunk/kaleido-core/src/main/java/org/kaleidofoundry/core/web/ServletContextProvider.java?r=505) does not have a `getServletContextLocal()` method.

**Conclusion:** What you've typed is likely a typo in the tutorial you read, probably referencing the most common interface available, `org.apache.portals.bridges.common.ServletContextProvider`, which has a `getServletContext(GenericPortlet portlet)` method.  What the tutorial likely intended to write is `getServletContextProvider().getServletContext(local)` where the `local` variable is a class extending `javax.portlet.GenericPortlet`.  The `getServletContext(local)` method would then return the `javax.servlet.ServletContext` which was associated with said variable.  Whether it is the same `javax.servlet.ServletContext` as returned by `getServletContext()` depends on where the `GenericPortlet` variable was assigned.

Do yourself a favor and cite the location of the tutorial to which you're referring.